# How to Remove whitespace between two text fields

Tags: php, html, css

I want to remove whitespace between the two text fields and center align them.
Code:

```
    <div class="form-row">
       <div class="col-3" id="fn1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" 
          name="firstName">
       </div></br>
       <div class="col-3" id="ln1">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" 
           name="lastName">
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I want to Remove the Whitespace between firstname and last name.

[image]

CSS Styling:

```
<style type="text/css">

p{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-family: initial;
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    .btn-outline-success{
        display: block; 
  margin: 0 auto;
    }

nav{
  float:right;
}

body{
  background-color: #F9F9FB;
}

.form-row > div{
      margin:0 auto;
      width:250px;

}

.col-3 > div
{
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Please, post a screenshot or something similar with your desired result. Also, what have you tried, and what went wrong?

Comment: obviously there is a style block somewhere in your code that is affecting the view but you did not share them here. Each box is in its own separate DIV and div possibly have padding and or margin. Plus  to center you mean center in its own div or center of the form row?

Comment: after looking at the screenshot... I'd say put them both in the same div/column and work with Widths. Also you might need to do display:inline-block so they don't appear in 2 rows.

Comment: @NawedKhan Thanks for the help but when i moved the two fields in same div tag
but the styling is not changing anything.. would you please elaborate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put both input fields to the same div/column and define widths as 50% (even less like 47% to accommodate any padding or margin)

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-3" id="fn1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control half-input" placeholder="First name" name="firstName">

    <input type="text" class="form-control half-input" placeholder="Last name" name="lastName">
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice that both fields are in same div and I have added a new class to these two: "half-input". The style definition is

```
.half-input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 47%;
}
```

Here is the working [JSFidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfd80mLy/)